# Traefik external services receiving 404 page not found

Tags: docker, traefik

I currently have Traefik installed in Docker alongside a few other docker containers. I am able to access those docker containers successfully, however, when I configure Traefik for any external services via the File Service, I receive the standard "404 page not found" error. I am able to successfully resolve these addresses directly, along with using Curl in terminal. Also, I have run the logs in DEBUG mode but I was not able to find any errors or 'smoking guns'. Also, the Traefik UI does not show any errors or possible problem areas.

Heres my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=******
      - CF_API_KEY=*****
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`monitor.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:****"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`monitor.example`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=example.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.example.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

**traefik.yml**

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

log:
    level: error

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml

certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: ******
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
```

**config.yml**

```
http:
  routers:
    weather:
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
      rule: "Host(`example.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers

      tls: {}
      service: weather
    
    synology:
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
      rule: "Host(`nas.example.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
      tls: {}
      service: synology
      
  services:
    weather:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.0.8:80"
        passHostHeader: false

    synology:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://192.168.0.3:5001"
        passHostHeader: false

  middlewares:
 
    https-redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        sslRedirect: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true

    default-whitelist:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
        - "10.0.0.0/24"
        - "192.168.0.0/24"
        - "172.0.0.0/8"

    secured:
      chain:
        middlewares:
        - default-whitelist
        - default-headers
```

And here is the **docker-compose.yml for Portainer** that I am able to resolve successfully.

```
version: '3'

services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`portainer.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I feel like this is a simple fix however I have been tearing my hair out trying to find a solution. Does anyone have any idea or suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was that the HTTP calls werent being rerouted to HTTPS. Adding the below to my traefik.yml resolved my problem:

```
    - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
    - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
    - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)
    - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=http
    - traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=https_redirect
```